# problems in simple ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $R$ be a simple ring.

(a) Show that for $a,b \in R$ if $aRb = 0$ then $a=0$ or $b=0$.

(b) The center or $R$ is either $\{0\}$ or a field.

(C) $R^{n}=R$ for any positive integer n.

I just study ideal/ring so that I don't familiar in how to solve it. A idea about the question, in question I think it is similar to the definition of domain. Is there any relation between domain and simple? (b)(c) I have no idea how to solve it.

Comment: $c)$ is false for some simple rings, unless you require there to be an identity, and if you require identity the second half of $b)$ never occurs... so I have to ask: are you requiring an identity?

Comment: It is a question for my algebra textbook, that's the whole question.

Comment: So it is totally out of the question that you might *try* to determine what the book requires? I guess it's fine if you don't, you'll just have to be happy with the help you get, if you don't clarify.

Comment: There is no relationship between domains and simple rings in general. There are simple domains and there are nonsimple domains. For commutative rings, of course, simple rings are fields, which are domains.

Comment: If $R$ has no identity, then (c) is false for the ring $R=\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ with trivial multiplication. Its ideals are just $\{0\}$ and $R$, but $R^2=\{0\}$. And also (b) is false.

Comment: But the definition of simple is $R^{2} /neq o$ and the only ideal of $R$ is 0 and $R$ itself? Should I consider $R^{2}={0}$ ?

Comment: @user131605 I suspected that, but you really should make clear what definitions you're using. For me rings have an identity, unless otherwise stated (and it's not only me).

Answer (score 2):

I'm betting you are assuming the rings have identity.

Hints:

(c) $R^n$ is an ideal of $R$, and since it contains $1$, it's nonzero, so...

(a) If $aRb=\{0\}$, then $(RaR)(RbR)=\{0\}$. Is it possible for this to happen if both ideals are zero? (Think about (c).)

(b) If $c$ is in the center, then $cR$ is an ideal of $R$ so...

Comment: For (c), I try $R^{2}=R$, since R is an ideal of R by the definition of simple. $R^{2} \le R$, also $R \le R^{2}$, that is $R^{2}=R$, by induction, $R^{n}=R^{n-1}*R=...=R^{2}=R$, is it right?

Comment: There are only two ideals for R, 0 or R. Isn't it possible RaR=RbR={0}?

Comment: @user131605 yes, that is one possibility. Why would that be a problem? You are trying to prove at least one of a,b is zero.

Answer (score 0):

We suppose the rings have identity.
A probably too powerfull theorem tells us $R$ is isomorphoc to $n \times n$ matrix ring over a division field $k$, thus every question is trivial. In particular (b) is $0$ when $n=1$ and $\lambda I$ otherwise.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_ring

Comment: zzzz. Can i just use latex to write formulas? :)

Comment: Have a look at this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: Is it able to solve without using Wedderburn's theorem?

Comment: Thank you for the Tutorial @saz

Comment: Field or division ring?

Comment: ops. Yes division ring!

Comment: There is no such theorem. There is such a theorem for Artinian simple rings, but not simple rings in general.

Comment: As i can read on note 1 here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artin%E2%80%93Wedderburn_theorem every simple ring is Artinian.

Comment: It has no proper ideals so i mean there are no ideal chains to evaluate!

Comment: @Pocahontas you are reading it incorrectly. You must consider chains of right ideals to determine if it is right Artinian, and chains of left ideals to see if it is left Artinian. "Artinian" means that it is Artinian on both sets of ideals, not just the two-sided ideals.

Comment: @rschwieb Thank you very much that was so much usefull! If i dont go wrong i think a good counterexample to my statement is $M_{nxn}(\mathbb{Z})$ or $M_{nxn}(\mathbb{Z}[X])$. They are not commutative rings with Identity, they are simple cause raws are left ideals and columns are right ideals so there are no two-sided proper ideals, and they are not Artinian cause i can create a left (or right) chain of discendant ideals for example asking the 1st column to be divisible by 2, then to be divisible by 6 and so on. Is that right?

Comment: @Pocahontas neither one of those rings is simple. A [Weyl algebra](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weyl_algebra) is an example of a simple domain that isn't Artinian.

Comment: Ok now i get it! Thank you very much @rschwieb